# Is there a way to see the most popular "favorite" questions?

Tags: support, questions, statistics, bookmarks, stackql

I'm trying to find some good questions on stackoverflow to answer this [question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2922/what-question-from-your-site-shows-the-magic-of-the-stackexchange-platform). To start my search, I thought it would be good to look at the list of the most popular favorite questions. It is probably obvious but I couldn't find a way to sort the questions by how many each one has been marked as a favorite.

Is there a way get a list of the questions sorted by favorite count?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Why [yes there is](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/104103/top-100-most-favorited-questions-on-so)

```
id      count   Title
9033    1185    Hidden Features of C#?
234075  918 What is your best programmer joke?
84556   877 What's your favorite "programmer" cartoon?
72394   816 What should a developer know before building a public web site?
1711    706 What is the single most influential book every programmer should read?    
58640   632 Great programming quotes
194812  483 List of freely available programming books
184618  479 What is the best comment in source code you have ever encountered?
662956  397 Most useful free .NET libraries?
38210   388 What non-programming books should programmers read?
164432  376 What real life bad habits has programming given you?
101268  367 Hidden features of Python
182112  364 Funny loading statements to keep users amused
406760  354 What's your most controversial programming opinion?
1644    338 What good technology podcasts are out there?
76364   309 What is the single most effective thing you did to improve your programming skills?    
78756   302 What do you use to keep notes as a developer?
```

Comment: Thanks. That does answer the question. Unfortunately it looks like my idea that the most popular favorite questions would also include the best questions that show off the strength of the stackoverflow platform isn't quite true.

Comment: In much the same way as the top-voted questions/answers typically aren't the best, either -- as I read somewhere yesterday, "the crowd isn't always wise".

Comment: @David: You should be able to use tags to refine the results.

Comment: @Bill the Lizard, Why i can't arrive the link ? http://stackql.net/default.aspx?qid=12767 Can SE users use it ?

Comment: @Soner: It looks like StackQL is down.  Here's a SEDE query for [Top 100 Most Favorited Questions on SO](http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/97831/top-100-most-favorited-questions-on-so).

Comment: @Bill Thanks. Is there any query for other StackExchange sites ? (meta.stackoverflow, productivity, superuser etc..)

Comment: @Soner: Yeah, you can run the same query on any of the sites.  Just click one of the site logo icons above the output.

Comment: @Bill Thanks. I couldn't find for productivity btw,

Comment: @Soner: Oh, yeah.  None of the Beta sites are in the data dump, which is where SEDE gets its data.  So none of those sites are queryable yet.

Comment: Link no longer works :/

Comment: @BilltheLizard neither does your SEDE query :/

Comment: @MarkMayo Thanks, I updated it.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know about [this](http://stackql.net/default.aspx?qid=12767) link on Tom Ritter's answer as it asks for login, but I tried to use data.stackexchange.com site, and I build a [query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/s/738/list-most-favorite-questions) that can help you.