# How can browse through the questions based on number of people added as favorite

Tags: feature-request, statistics, bookmarks

I want to go through all the questions in order of favorite to the users.

Can anybody help me out?
Do we have this feature already?

I'm just curious what kind of question people like most.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/badges/36/stellar-question Badge is awarded to users whose Question are favorited by 100 users! does it help?

Comment: @Narayan Thanks for link. But If there is direct navigation available that will be great!

Comment: @Narayan: No, because that gives a list of users, not questions.

Comment: well i agree, but i found http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/44237/how-to-search-questions-marked-as-favorites-on-so

http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/34542/search-within-favorites-closed

http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/30484/is-there-a-way-to-see-the-most-popular-favorite-questions this by searching, u need to query the datadump to get what u required

Answer (score 1):

Well I tried to use http://data.stackexchange.com site.

Here is a [query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/s/738/list-most-favorite-questions). May be that can help you.